# Undefined name state for flutter bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

Im trying to use the flutter_bloc v8 for a counter app but I can't access the value of the state to update it. Its telling me state is undefined. I know we can simplify it by using Cubit but I want to see how it'll work with normal bloc.

**counter_state.dart**

```
abstract class CounterState {}

class CounterValue extends CounterState {
  int value;
  CounterValue(this.value);
}

class CounterLoading extends CounterState {}
```

**counter_bloc.dart**

```
class CounterBloc extends Bloc<CounterEvent, CounterState> {
  CounterBloc() : super(CounterValue(0)) {
    on<IncrementEvent>((event, emit) => _increment(emit));
    on<DecrementEvent>((event, emit) => _decrement(emit));
  }
}

void _increment(Emitter<CounterState> emit) {
  emit(CounterValue(state.value + 1));
}

void _decrement(Emitter<CounterState> emit) {
  emit(CounterValue(state.value + 1));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the state is unreachable because you have defined your functions outside of CounterBloc.

try this:

```
class CounterBloc extends Bloc<CounterEvent, CounterState> {
  CounterBloc() : super(CounterValue(0)) {
    on<IncrementEvent>((event, emit) => _increment(emit));
    on<DecrementEvent>((event, emit) => _decrement(emit));
  }

  void _increment(Emitter<CounterState> emit) {
    emit(CounterValue(state.value + 1));
  }

  void _decrement(Emitter<CounterState> emit) {
    emit(CounterValue(state.value + 1));
  }
}
```

Comment: ahh yes. I didnt notice that. Thanks but now Im getting "The getter 'value' isn't defined for the type 'CounterState'" on state.value

Comment: you should cast the state to CountrValue. please accept the answer if it was helpful. thanks

Comment: I've accepted the answer but sorry, how do we cast a state ?

Comment: replace `state.value` with `(state as CountrValue).value`. accept please not upvote :)

Comment: done. Im still getting The getter 'value' isn't defined for the type 'CounterValue'.

Comment: `void _increment(Emitter<CounterState> emit) {
    emit(CounterValue((state as CounterValue).value + 1));
  }
` it works for me.

Comment: working good now. thanks