# Undefined name 'state' for flutter bloc version 8.0.0

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am trying to access `bloc` (using newest version of `flutter_bloc: 8.0.0`) `state` value within `BlocBuilder`, but I keep getting error that `state` is undefined. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70485548/12071531) to similar question, but that's not the issue. `SetInitialValuesEvent` is added when `ConvertBloc` is initialised and `_onSetInitialValuesEventToState()` is being called as well.

Only thing I could think of to try was checking if `state` is defined (accessible) in `BlocConsumer` listener (and it is):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return BlocConsumer<ConvertBloc, ConvertState>(
          listener: (context, state) {
          //defined / accessible
          print("------- ${state.unitSystemFrom}");
          },
          builder: (context, sate) {
          //undefined / not accessible
            return Text(state.unitSystemFrom);
          },
        );
      }
```

**Widget build method:**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ConvertBloc, ConvertState>(
      builder: (context, sate) {
        return Text(state.unitSystemFrom);
      },
    );
  }
```

**Set initial values event from bloc:**

```
class SetInitialValuesEvent extends ConvertEvent {
  final String unitSystemFrom;
  final double unitValueFrom;
  final String unitFrom;
  final String unitSystemTo;
  final double unitValueTo;
  final String unitTo;

  const SetInitialValuesEvent(
    this.unitSystemFrom,
    this.unitValueFrom,
    this.unitFrom,
    this.unitSystemTo,
    this.unitValueTo,
    this.unitTo,
  );

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
        unitSystemFrom,
        unitValueFrom,
        unitFrom,
        unitSystemTo,
        unitValueTo,
        unitTo
      ];
}
```

**Bloc:**

```
class ConvertBloc extends Bloc<ConvertEvent, ConvertState> {
  ConvertBloc()
      : super(const ConvertState(
            unitSystemFrom: '',
            unitValueFrom: 0,
            unitFrom: '',
            unitSystemTo: '',
            unitValueTo: 0,
            unitTo: '')) {
    on<SetInitialValuesEvent>(_onSetInitialValuesEventToState);
  }

  void _onSetInitialValuesEventToState(
      SetInitialValuesEvent event, Emitter<ConvertState> emit) {
    emit(ConvertState(unitSystemFrom: event.unitSystemFrom,
        unitValueFrom: event.unitValueFrom,
        unitFrom: event.unitFrom,
        unitSystemTo: event.unitSystemTo,
        unitValueTo: event.unitValueTo,
        unitTo: event.unitTo))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have a Typo:

You used `sate` in the build function params but tried accessing it with `state`

Like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ConvertBloc, ConvertState>(
      builder: (context, sate) {
        return Text(state.unitSystemFrom);
      },
    );
  }
```

Use this instead:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ConvertBloc, ConvertState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Text(state.unitSystemFrom);
      },
    );
  }
```